# AWS Cognito login to return as JSON

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have this link :
https://{application}.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id={clientid}&redirect_uri=http://localhost

Above link will direct me to login page of Cognito.
How do I return the respond as JSON so I can set up the token in cookie or indexedDB ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching Cognito.

The OpenId URLs like `/oauth2/authorize` are part of the [Hosted UI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-userpools-server-contract-reference.html).  The redirected requests are meant to go to a browser, and you can't configure these to use JSON.

What you will be more interested in is [Cognito's API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).  Requests and responses are all JSON; for example, the [`InitiateAuth` endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html) is analogous to the `/authorize` endpoint of the Hosted UI.

The part I'm struggling with is that the Hosted UI supports OIDC features like PKCE for sending an authorization code to a server to securely pass the identity.  The API doesn't seem to have anything like this.